# FusionChart not displaying on remote host

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo, fusioncharts

i created chart using Fusionchart and PHP mysql which runs well on my localhost, but when deployed on the remote/cloud server, rather than display chart information, it displays a string "chart not supported". The error log on the remote server indicates that an error on line 44 i.e. where the query is executed. Please could you use your knowledge and experience to resolve this problem. I have written the code below

```
<?php
include("include/fusioncharts.php");

$hostdb = "localhost";  // MySQl host
$userdb = "root";  // MySQL username
$passdb = "";  // MySQL password
$namedb = "power_generation";  // MySQL database name

// Establish a connection to the database
$dbhandle = new mysqli($hostdb, $userdb, $passdb, $namedb);

/*Render an error message, to avoid abrupt failure, if the database   connection parameters are incorrect */
if ($dbhandle->connect_error) {
 exit("There was an error with your connection: ".$dbhandle->connect_error);
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Peak Generation</title>

 <!-- You need to include the following JS file to render the chart.
When you make your own charts, make sure that the path to this JS file is correct.
Else, you will get JavaScript errors. -->

<script src="javafile/fusioncharts.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<?php

    // Form the SQL query that returns the top 10 most populous countries
    $strQuery = "select SUM(peak_generation) as TotOutput, pdate, plant_id FROM daily_report WHERE pdate BETWEEN '2015-05-01' AND '2015-05-30' GROUP BY pdate";

    // Execute the query, or else return the error message.
    $result = $dbhandle->query($strQuery) or exit("Error code ({$dbhandle->errno}): {$dbhandle->error}");



    // If the query returns a valid response, prepare the JSON string
    if ($result) {
        // The `$arrData` array holds the chart attributes and data
        $arrData = array(
            "chart" => array(
              "caption" => "Peak Generation",
              "paletteColors" => "#0075c2",
              "bgColor" => "#ffffff",
              "borderAlpha"=> "20",
              "canvasBorderAlpha"=> "0",
              "usePlotGradientColor"=> "0",
              "plotBorderAlpha"=> "10",
              "showXAxisLine"=> "1",
              "xAxisLineColor" => "#999999",
              "showValues" => "0",
              "divlineColor" => "#999999",
              "divLineIsDashed" => "1",
              "showAlternateHGridColor" => "0",
              "decimalPrecision" => "1",
               "formatNumberScale" => "0"

            )
        );

        $arrData["data"] = array();

// Push the data into the array
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        array_push($arrData["data"], array(
            "label" => $row["pdate"],
            "value" => $row["TotOutput"],
            "link" => "testcode.php?daily_report=". $row["pdate"]
            )
        );
        }

        /*JSON Encode the data to retrieve the string containing the JSON representation of the data in the array. */

        $jsonEncodedData = json_encode($arrData);

        $columnChart = new FusionCharts("Column3D", "myFirstChart" , 1000, 500, "chart", "json", $jsonEncodedData);

        // Render the chart
        $columnChart->render();

        // Close the database connection
        $dbhandle->close();
    }

  ?>


   </head>

   <body>
  <div id="container">
  <div id="chart"><!-- Fusion Charts will render here--></div>

  </div>
  </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: `an error on line 44` You think everyone has access to your log and know the error, right?

Comment: Maybe this appear due to some missing data in db? .. try to export the db from localhost and import it to your server.. if the error is not shown then you should handle missing data before trying to display any chart

Comment: am sorry, this is line 44 ---------$result = $dbhandle->query($strQuery) or exit("Error code ({$dbhandle->errno}): {$dbhandle->error}");

Comment: it works well on my localhost, and displays chart on browser , but when i move the file to remote sever and included the filepath on my remote host, it displays no chart, but when i query without passing it to the chart object it returns rows of data. i developed the chart on windows environment and my remote host cPanel is a linux system....could this be the problem?

Comment: There are different parts on this problem and you need to debug one by one. First check whether we get the data from your database without even using the FusionCharts. This will ensure your connection and DB is working as expected. Then apply FusionCharts with a static data and see if it renders, if it does then you know the problem is somewhere else. If it does not, which is likely, cross check your network tab (dev tools) to figure out missing files.

Comment: Thanks pallabB, i tried pulling data from my database, and it displayed, then i tried displaying chat using static xml just as you said, it displayed. i found out there there is a file missing, immediatly i included the file in my project, Boom, it pops up.. u a star